# Setting up Debian squirrelmail

Tags: debian, imap, squirrelmail

I'm new to networking.

I need to set up a email server and I also need to create an email address.
ex.

> muazam@mydomain.com

I've installed squirrelmail and dovecot.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/squirrelmail/src/login.php
```

Shows a log in screen, but when I try to log in I get this error:

> Error connecting to IMAP server:
>   127.0.0.1. 111 : Connection refused

I have no experience with squirrelmail and dovecote.
Anyone can help me out, I really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need an SMTP-server. I suggest postfix. (`apt-get install postfix`)
Then, you should make sure that you use the `~/Maildir'. If this folder doesn't exist or you gave it the wrong permissions, this is a common error. Make sure you configure Postfix to use it:

```
postconf -e "home_mailbox = Maildir/"
postconf -e "mailbox_command = "
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

If it is still not working, try telnetting into your machine and test it that way.

### Test SMTP (port 25)

```
Trying 10.0.1.40...
Connected to test.freetown.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 test.freetown.local ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo test.freetown.local
mail from: bart@test.freetown.local
rcpt to: root@test.freetown.local
data
Subject: First Mail

Looking good!
.
quit
```

### Test IMAP (port 143)

```
Trying 10.0.1.40...
Connected to test.freetown.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE ACL ACL2=UNION] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2010 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
a login bart bart
a OK LOGIN Ok.
a logout
* BYE Courier-IMAP server shutting down
a OK LOGOUT completed
```

### Test POP3 (port 110)

```
Trying 10.0.1.40...
Connected to test.freetown.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Hello there.
user bart
+OK Password required.
pass bart
+OK logged in.
quit
+OK Bye-bye.
```

If that works, your squirlmail should be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial: http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny (yes, it's overkill, but you'll learn something from it).